# OSError at /en/ Django Saleor webpack error

Tags: django, saleor

I am trying Django Saleor to experience ECommerce framework. 
But I get this error. 
And I even tried finding the project root, I couldn't find webapck-bundle.json.

*This is the error of my django debug page*

```
OSError at /en/
Error reading /workspace/saleor/saleor/webpack-bundle.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Install Node.js](https://docs.getsaleor.com/docs/getting-started/installation-macos/#nodejs)
2. [npm install](https://docs.getsaleor.com/docs/getting-started/installation-macos/#8-install-front-end-dependencies)
3. [Prepare front-end assets](https://docs.getsaleor.com/docs/getting-started/installation-macos/#9-prepare-front-end-assets)
4. [Start the development server](https://docs.getsaleor.com/docs/getting-started/installation-macos/#11-start-the-development-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i
npm run build-assets --production
```